# What is a common reason that Empires fall or collapse and can they be corrected?

Tags: economy, political-history, civil-war

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any similarities in what happens when Empires collapse?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2168/are-there-any-similarities-in-what-happens-when-empires-collapse)

The question I have is 2 fold what causes most Empires or Nations to fall other than over powered by a superior foe?  Is there anyway to prevent an empire or nation from falling once events are set in place?

Pretty much the main reasons for a nation or empire falling is civil strife, economic collapse, population collapse or cultural shock (and any others). I want to know what seems to be the most common.

The second part is more once a nation/empire begins to fall is there anything to stop it or is it human nature to accept the destruction as a unchangeable event.